# jquery menu buttonset problem

Tags: jquery, menu, uibutton

made a menu out of the following code but the original href in the top 'edit' link doesn't work any more?

original html code.

```
 <div class="mediaOptionsButtonSet">
  <button class="mediaOptionsButton">media options</button>
 </div>

 <ul class="mediaOptionsMenu">
  <li><a href="/youradmin_v2/media/edit/<?=$row['mediaID']?>" class="mediaEdit">edit</a></li>
  <li>
   <a lang="<?=$row['mediaID']?>" href="<?=$row['pathToFile']."/".$row['mediaID']."/".$row['filename']?>" rel="prettyPhoto[pp_gal]" title="<?=$row['title']?>" class="mediaView">view</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" class="mediaCrop">crop</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="mediaDuplicate">duplicate</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" class="mediaPublish active">active</a></li>
 </ul>
```

after button set applied;

```
<li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem">
  <a href="/youradmin_v2/media/edit/2371" class="mediaEdit ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-icon ui-state-hover ui-state-active" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="-1" id="ui-active-menuitem">
    <span class="ui-button-icon-primary ui-icon ui-icon-wrench"></span>
    <span class="ui-button-text">edit</span>
  </a>
</li>
```

and menu code is;

```
$("a.mediaEdit").button({
   icons: {
     primary: 'ui-icon-wrench'
   } 
});

$(".mediaOptionsButtonSet button").button({
   icons: {
     primary: 'ui-icon-gear',
     secondary: 'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'
   },
   text: false
}).click( function() {
   var menu = $(this).parent().next().show().position({
      my: "right top",
      at: "right top",
      of: this,
   });
   menu.css('z-index',2000);
   $(document).one("click", function() {
      menu.hide();
   });
   menu.bind("mouseleave", function(event, ui) {
      menu.hide();
   });
   return false;
})
  .parent()
  .buttonset()
  .next()
  .hide()
  .menu();
```

doen anyone know how i can get the href to stay as the default action?

best, Dan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("a", ".demo").click(function () { window.location = this.href });
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dBbe8/ based on this simple demo I made, after applying `.button()` on the link, it still work. Maybe you got any other issues there. Like is there any error being reported by the console?.. or any other?..

Comment: hey Reigel - no errors so think it might be the menu actions interfereing with the button actions...

http://jsfiddle.net/dBbe8/2/